# What does the Red button of a computer inside Hollywood sewer do?

Tags: wasteland-2

After I pressed it, someone said "This can't be good" and ground's shaking. I thought water should fill in this sewer or something but no, nothing else happened.

Is there any event about it? Or is it some kind of easter egg?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing when I saw that.

Comment: As far as the internet goes, everyone have no clue of what this button does - https://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/613937306659583365/ - https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=11318 - http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/664099-wasteland-2/faqs/70854?page=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an achievement for pressing it. A Steam user is mentioning it on [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/613937943137324433/?l=english) (tenth comment) and it is confirmed by the [Wasteland 2 Achievements Gamepedia Page](http://wasteland.gamepedia.com/Wasteland_2_achievements). The achievement is called "Pushed the button".

Also, this [Achievements Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=343414185&insideModal=1) tells you exactly how and where to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this walkthrough](http://guides.gamepressure.com/wasteland2/guide.asp?ID=27032) of the game...

> **Computer** – Suspicious computer, with big dagerous<sup>[sic]</sup> looking red button... After pushing him ground will shake, but nothing more happens.

It's no more than a quick bout of humor.